# How to run python programs in pycharm with passing parameters?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently having problem running python programs in pycharm, I generally used to right click and run the program. I want to run the program like this:

`python hrllo.py rahulkapoo vit university`

Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rahul/PycharmProjects/untitled/hrllo.py", line 107, in <module>
    aggregate()
  File "C:/Users/rahul/PycharmProjects/untitled/hrllo.py", line 88, in aggregate
    br = login()
  File "C:/Users/rahul/PycharmProjects/untitled/hrllo.py", line 23, in login
    response = br.open('https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/stud_login.asp')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 255, in _mech_open
    raise response
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: request disallowed by robots.txt

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: whats your expected result? Can you post your code? What are you saying here `python hrllo.py rahulkapoor vit university i don't know how to do this :`? is this what you're typing into a console or terminal?

Comment: On the right top of the window select your script and then click on edit configuration and enter you parameter in the box below where your script appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PyCharm, right-click on the script (or within the editor window that has the script open, click `Create 'scriptname'`, put your params in the `Script Parameters` box near the top and click `OK`.

The new run config will appear to the left of the run button at the top of Pycharm (at least in my version it does). Now make sure that the new run config is listed when running the script.