# Gun Violence Data Source Code Run Error from Github? (End, Output Error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, output, argparse

I am having trouble utilizing an open source project that I will be utilizing in the near future. ([Gun Violence Data/Code](https://github.com/jamesqo/gun-violence-data)).  The data that is available through Github is only up to 2018 and I would like to run the scripts to acquire data up to Jan 2020, however I have run into a snag during the "stage1.py" running.

This is the error I am receiving:

```
usage: stage1.py [-h] [-d] START END OUTFILE
stage1.py: error: the following arguments are required: END, OUTFILE
```

For this [code](https://github.com/jamesqo/gun-violence-data/blob/master/scripts/stage1.py)

I am unsure how to advance from this error since I have never seen it before and can not find anything on it.  I asssume it has to do with the argpars, but that is just a guess.  I have tried tinkering with imports, argpars, and other parts of the code to get it to work, but to no avail.

Edit:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
if targets_specific_month:
    month, year = map(int, parts)
    end_day = monthrange(year, month)[1]

    args.start_date = '{}-01-{}'.format(month, year)
    args.end_date = '{}-{}-{}'.format(month, end_day, year)
    args.output_file = 'stage1.{:02d}.{:04d}.csv'.format(month, year)
return args
```

Comment: You need to provide these values when starting the script. If running from `pycharm` you may need to set those command line parameters in separate window.  I don't use 'pycharm' so can't help with the details, but the error has come up often on SO.

Comment: https://www.askpython.com/python/python-command-line-arguments, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884252/how-to-run-python-programs-in-pycharm-with-passing-parameters

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states what is needed you need to provide three arguments to the script, `START`, `END` and `OUTFILE`, which corresponds to the Start Date, End Date and Output file name.

Start Date and End Date has to be in the following format: month/date/Year

Comment: Are you saying I should edit the '{}-01-{}' sections of the code (in the edit) for the dates I want to pull from?  Because I am trying to change those to no avail, should I try changing the 'stage1.{:02d}.{:04d}.csv' instead?

Comment: You should supply them as arguments when running stage1.py. Like this: `python stage1.py "01/01/2018" "01/01/2020" some_file.txt`

Comment: He may be using `pycharm` which has a different way of providing the command line arguments.

Comment: I am using pycharm, how would I go about using _blues_ suggestion?

Comment: Would it be something like this, `stage1.py "01/01/2018" "02/01/2018" stage.1.01.2018.csv` from the terminal?    I want to perform it for all combinations of months and years on a loop, is that possible?

Comment: @AntasSantas _I am using pycharm, how would I go about using blues suggestion?_ Have you done any research?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102272/pycharm-and-sys-argv-arguments